# Safely disconnecting an inductor

Tags: inductor

How is it possible to safely disconnect/turn off an inductor that has current through it without causing a huge backward voltage? Even dropping from a circuit with low current, it the current will still be going from finite to 0, in a very small space of time (how would you calculate this time?), causing a big voltage spike. How can inductors possibly be safe if disconnecting them is so dangerous?

Comment: Disconnecting from where?

Comment: Without details, we cannot give you an answer.

Comment: You don't normally disconnect components from a circuit while it's operating, so their safety in doing this is irrelevant.

Comment: @Finbarr Are you familiar with switches or buttons?
 Disconnecting components from active circuits is routine. I would wonder how you stop anything from operating otherwise, let alone changing its state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a [flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode).

Knowing the name, you can search regarding your specific application, such as [for a relay](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/110574/15805).