# What is a suitable resistor value for this circuit?

Tags: resistors, circuit-design, relay, 12v, pir

See the small circuit of a PIR motion sensor below. I've tried to find more than one circuit online but every single time it shows a different value for the resistor.

I would be grateful if anyone can help me with this circuit. Also I would appreciate it if you could tell me if the circuit is correct and is going to work perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link to the data sheet for the PIR sensor and the relay. The schematic looks poorly designed too. No need for a resistor if the BJT is where it is but, putting it there is also a weakness.

Comment: Configured as an emitter follower, technically no resistor is needed here.

Comment: Hello Andy,
I have a little knowledge about the electronics materials, I'm trying to do a circuit for a light to be used only with motion sensor, I got the circuit diagram from the internet. could you please help me doing it more better.

Comment: This is a question and answer site.

Comment: Depends on what kind of output the PIR sensor has, and we don't know what PIR sensor it is and what kind of output it has. If you know, add it to the question. The transistor drives the relay as emitter follower instead of just switch.

Answer (score 0):

*Warning about mains voltages: do not attempt any of this if you're not competent with mains (120/220 VAC) voltages, which will kill you if you make a mistake.*

The textbook circuit for driving a relay with a transistor is the following, Circuit A p821 of [*The Art of Electronics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics), 3rd ed, Horowitz and Hill, one of the most influential textbooks.  This transistor is a "low side switch", ie, it performs a switching action on the low-voltage side of the load: "a switch to ground".

The input gate is your PIR sensor; the load is your relay and its diode.  You can use a *huge* range of NPN transistors in this position, including the BC547 you mention, and also the extremely common [2n2222](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2N2222).  The resistor of 1K shown in the example depends on the PIR sensor, which we don't know much about, and the relay current, which we don't know either.  The purpose of the resistor is to limit the current into the base; took much and the transistor will break.  Similarly, the purpose of [the diode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110574/how-to-choose-a-flyback-diode-for-a-relay/110576#110576) is to protect the transistor when the relay goes off and discharges its energy backwards.

The best way to find out the right resistor is to post the specifications of your relay (the critical parameter is the voltage and resistance of the coil) and at least the voltage output of the PIR detector.

[image]

You might build it as follows.  At the risk of sounding obvious: you test the relay portion works exactly how you want it *before* going anywhere near the mains voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG1sXz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>